# How can I see if an e-mail is signed in "Mail" (using an Exchange account)?

Tags: macos, mail.app, signature, smime

Usually, a signed message shows a checkmark icon. Clicking on this icon displays the certificate that was used to sign the message:

[image: Message on iCloud.com]

Not so when a message lies in an exchange mailbox, and is displayed with "Mail" on MacOS (tested up to 10.10):

[image: Message on Exchange account]

The iPad, on the other hand, handles the exact same message just fine. It is also connected via Exchange protocol to the server:

[image: Message on iPad]

So: How can I enable this also on "Mail" on OS X? Or is this a bug, or even a permanent restriction?

Comment: Still confirmed with Mail Version 8.1 (1993)

Comment: is your SSL turned on ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 What does this have to do with SSL? It is not about the encryption between the client and the server, it is about the SSL signature of the email. You cannot turn it off or on. But BTW yes: I fetch the emails with SSL.

Comment: @Matteo what are you talking about? Quote->"it is about the SSL signature of the email."

Comment: @Buscar웃 Of course but how can you turn it on and off? The email is signed with an SSL certificate. What do you mean by "SSL turned on"?

Comment: Still confirmed with 10.10.2 beta (Mail Version 8.2 (2064))

Answer (score 1):

It was most likely a bug. I had the same behaviour and after the latest update (10.10.2) Mail is showing the information again.

[image]

**Edit**

As commented by user2216335 the *Security* information is not always shown.

Apple Mail was able to recognise the signature from my example:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s;
smime-type=signed-data Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Description: S/MIME Cryptographic Signature
```

but not from a message sent by Apple Mail

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Comment: Agree, I now also see the icon as it should be on MacOS.

Comment: Actually I have to retract this statement: I can't see the icon anymore. I could see it on a ver old message, but I can't see it on a test message that I just sent.

Comment: @user2216335 After your comment I checked. Apple Mail is only able to validate some of the messages. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Does the **RFC 822 Name** in your certificate match the email address that you have listed in Apple Mail on your Mac? If you're not sure, double click on your certificate in Keychain Access to bring up the details and scroll down to the **RFC 822 Name** field. This email address must precisely match (including case sensitivity) the email address listed in your account's settings in Mail.

[image]

For example, if your **RFC 822 Name** is listed like this:

**username@email.com**

Check your email address to see what how closely it matches:

**username@email.com** - Exact match, certificate should appear

**Username@email.com** - Not exact match, certificate won't appear

**username@EMAIL.COM** - Not exact match, certificate won't appear

**UserName@email.com** - Not exact match, certificate won't appear

Comment: First of all the behaviour is for all signed emails that I receive (and not only mine). But more important if there is a certificate and it is **not** matching, the client should give an error and not ignore it. This is the idea of certificates, warning if the sender is not who he claims to be.

Comment: Same here: It's about mails that I receive, not mail that I send. So in the received mail with a signature, this signature is either valid or it's flawed in some way. In both cases, the mail client should indicate this. Apple mail does not do this if the mail server is connected via Exchange protocol. Outlook does, and Mail on iOS does as well.

Comment: Update: iOS no longer works correctly, with 8.1.2 I can't see the sign for the signature anymore. So at least iOS and MacOS are consistent now ;( As for the RFC822 name field: Yes, it matches exactly.